# Finite sets, bijective functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a beginners question. I'm trying to understand the definition of a finite set. So I read that a set $A$ is finite if there exists a bijection $f: A \rightarrow \{1,...,n\},$ for some positive integer $n$.

My understanding of a bijection is that it is a function where every element of one set is "paired" with an element of another set. So $f(x) = 2x$ is one example of a bijection.

So what if I have for example the set $A = \{1,3,4,7\}.$ Is that finite, because I can't think of a function that maps $A$ to $\{1,2,3,4\}?$

Or must a finite set be something like $B = \{5,10,15\},$ where $f(x) = x/5$ so $f$ maps $B$ to $\{1,2,3\}?$

If A is not a finite set, what is it then? Is there a third category (finite, infinite and then something else)?

Comment: For your set $A$ define $f(1)=1,f(3)=2,f(4)=3,f(7)=4$.

Comment: If you accept the law of excluded middle (every well-formed sentence has a definite truth value which is either "true" or "false"), then a set is either finite or infinite and not both. Simply because "infinite" is defined as "not finite". So if a set is finite, we're done, and if not, then it is infinite by definition. It cannot be both finite and not finite, and it cannot be neither by the law of excluded middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no rule that the function providing the bijection be "nice". So, in your example, we may just define a function $f$ whose domain is $\{1, 3, 4, 7\}$ as

- $f(1)=1$,
- $f(3)=2$,
- $f(4)=3$,
- $f(7)=4$.

This provides the needed bijection. (Note that it's not the only option - we could also e.g. send $1$ to $4$, $3$ to $3$, $4$ to $2$, and $7$ to $1$.)

Crucially, note that this $f$ is defined *only* on the original set $\{1, 3, 4, 7\}$ - it makes no sense to ask what $f(0)$ is (say), nor should it.

---

Incidentally, however, note that we could have done this with a polynomial via some appropriate *interpolation*. However, there's no actual reason to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You are running into the usual beginner's pitfall of only thinking about functions as polynomials. (There was a time in my mathematical life when I did the same thing.)
But a function $f \colon A \to B$ is *any* valid rule specifying a unique value $f(a) \in B$ for each $a \in A$, it need not have a "nice" closed equational form.

That being said, you could also intuitively think about the bijection $f \colon A \to \lbrace 1, \dotsc, n \rbrace$ as counting the elements of your finite set $A$, i.e. the element that is mapped to $1$ is the first element of $A$, the element that is mapped to $2$ is the second, ..., and the element that is mapped to $n$ is the $n$-th and last element of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Your set $\{1,3,4,7 \}$ is finite. A bijection with the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ would be the function $f$ that maps $1 \to 1$, $2 \to 3$, $3\to 4$ and $4\to 7$. The key here is that the range of the functions can be defined for each element separately.